# My first cloud project

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, cloud

A bit lost on where to start after exploring digitalcoean/aws.

I have looked at the documentation for [docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3), and docker seems to be the direction I want to go in (docker for AWS), but I am unsure that these are mutually exclusive solutions.

From what I understand the following workflow is possible:

1. Code local python (most any language, but I am using py)
2. Deploy local code (aka upload) to a server
3. Call that code from a local machine with some argument(s) via a script leveraging some cloud API (boto3/docker?)
4. Grab finished result file from my cloud (pull file that is JSON/CSV etc and contains my results) using an API (boto3/docker?)

I thought this would be way easier to get up and running (maybe it is, and I am just missing something).

I feel like I am hitting my head against the wall on something that is intended to not be so tough.

Any pointers/guidance are hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: question is too broad/vague and will probably be shut down because of this. docker and boto are orthogonal. you can write an use your application to use boto for doing the AWS related calls. on top of that you can use docker (ECS) or not to deploy your app. for starters I would recommend to keep it as simple as possible: use S3 to store input/outputs and just download from S3.

Comment: Check out Docker machine. It has a AWS driver for launching docker enables servers. https://docs.docker.com/machine/

Comment: @Mircea Can you provide a link to a tutorial that is useful to get up to speed?

Comment: I would look at the AWS SDK to understand what the various services are and what they do.

Answer (score 0):

boto3 is an interface to aws.

docker is a software tool for managing images and deploying them as containers.

You can use boto3 to create your amazon machine, and then install docker on that machine, and pull containers from a docker repository to run them.

There's also solutions like docker-machine(docker-toolbox for windows/mac) that can be used to create machines on amazon and then run your containers directly on that machine from your local docker repository.